# Enter vrMode in aframejs

Tags: javascript, aframe

If i use the aframe js locally i am able to switch to stereoscopic mode directly on page load using :

```
if (scene.hasLoaded) {
scene.enterVR();
}
```

i have two js files on my website, aframe and bmfont:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component/master/dist/aframe-bmfont-text-component.min.js"></script>
```

So if i reference the local file of aframejs, bmfont doesn't work.
And if i use the remote copy.. or the online version.. enterVR mode doesn't work.

https://github.com/smsejwan/aframe

Comment: What browser, what device?

Comment: @ngokevin I have tried this on Nexus 6p, Iphone 6s, Galaxy S7, Macbook and iMac.
and Browser Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

`enterVR()` requires a user action because of browser security.

Maybe using it locally rather than on a webserver bypass that but then you encounter other problems (e.g. assets not loading).

There are ways to trick the browser (e.g. assign a shortcut then use a script like AHK to periodically call it) but it's not recommended.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying, Can you explain more about Shortcut?

Comment: by default the `f` key is the shortcut to enter VR/fullscreen